# How is heart to be understood in Rom. 10:10

Tags: greek, hebrew, romans

The Old Testament makes a [distinction](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/58745/luke-2438-hearts-or-minds) at times, it seems between *heart* as center of thoughts (modern mind) and *kidneys* as center of emotions(also Revelation 2:23 makes the distinction).
However, I’m not sure if that distinctions is consistent across OT.

In Romans 10:10, Paul writes:

> For it is with your heart that you believe and are justified, and it
> is with your mouth that you profess your faith and are saved.

Using the Greek kardias (heart). However, elsewhere he uses the term mind (Romans 1:28).

How are we to understand Paul’s meaning of heart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meaning of "heart", καρδία, in the NT is well attested by any good lexicon.  With the exception of Matt 12:40 ("heart of the earth"), the meaning of kadia in the NT is always:

> καρδία denotes the seat and center of all physical and spiritual life [Thayer]

BDAG is the same:

> Heart as seat of physical, spiritual and mental life
>
> (a) as the center and source of physical life, Acts 14:17, James 5:5
>
> (b) as center and source of the whole inner life with its thinking,
> feeling, and volition of humans whether in their pre-Christian or
> Christian experience
>
> - in an all-inclusive sense, Luke 16:15; 1 Thess 2:4, Rom 8:27, Rev 2:23, Heb 4:12; 1 Cor 14:24; 1 Peter 3:4; Rom 6:17; Matt 18:35; 1 Tim
>   1:5; 2 Tim 2:22; 1 Peter 1:22; Matt 15:8, 18; Mark 7:6; Rom 10:8, 9,
>   10; 2 Cor 6:11; Eph 5:19; Col 3:16, etc
> - of inner awareness, 2 Cor 4:6; Eph 1:18; 2 Peter 1:19, etc
> - of the will and its decisions, 2 Cor 9:7, Luke 21:14, Acts 5:4, 11:23; John 13:2, etc
> - of moral decisions, the moral life, of vices and virtues, James 4:8, Acts 15:9, Matt 5:8, etc
> - of the emotions, wishes, desires, Rom 1:24; Matt 5:28, 12:34f; Luke 6:45, 12:34, 24:32; James 3:14, 5:8; Acts 2:26, etc
> - especially of love, Matt 12:30, 33; Luke 10:27; Matt 22:37; Luke 1:17; Phil 1:7
> - of disposition, Luke 1:51, Eph 6:5, Col 3:22, Acts 2:46, Matt 11:25, Col 3:15
> - as the dwelling place of heavenly powers and beings, Rom 5:5; 2 Cor 1:22, Gal 4:6, Eph 3:17

[See also the appendix below.]

Thus, Rom 10:8-10 correctly states that:

> But what does it say? “The word is near you; it is in your mouth and
> in your heart,” that is, the word of faith we are proclaiming: that if
> you confess with your mouth, “Jesus is Lord,” and believe in your
> heart that God raised Him from the dead, you will be saved. For with
> your heart you believe and are justified, and with your mouth you
> confess and are saved.

Thus, "heart" here is the inner conviction of the truth that Jesus has risen from the dead, not merely a flippant mental assent!

**APPENDIX - Another word, "nous" = "mind"**

Note that καρδία (kardia, heart) slightly overlaps with another Greek word, νοῦς (nous, "mind") which has come into English with the same meaning.  According to BDAG, **νοῦς (nous)** has this meaning:

> 1. **The faculty of intellectual perception**
>
> - (a) mind, intellect, Rom 7:22, 23
> - (b) understanding, mind as facility of thinking, Luke 24:45, Rom 13:18, 17:19, Phil 4:7
>
> 2. **way of thinking, *mind, attitude*** as the sum total of the whole mental and moral state of being
>
> - (a) as possessed by every person, Rom 12:2, Eph 4:23, Rom 1:28, etc
> - (b) specifically of the Christian attitude or way of thinking, 1 Cor 1:10
>
> 3. **result of thinking, *mind, thought opinion, decree***, Rom 14:5, 11:34; 1 Cor 2:16